# Не могу настроить дебаг в PyCharm для Django внутри Docker'а

Tags: django, docker, pycharm, devops

Хочу все рабочее окружение поместить внутрь docker контейнеров, но при этом иметь возможность пользоваться инструментами отладки и раздельного запуска тестов в PyCharm используя эту фичу:
[PyCharm Remote Interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html)

Имею следующие конфиги:

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 0

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r ./requirements.txt
```

`docker-compose.dev.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:

  web:
    container_name: django-first-ci-dev--web
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/django-ci
    working_dir: /django-ci
    env_file:
      - .envs
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'

  postgres:
    container_name: django-first-ci-dev--postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - ./docker-volumes-dev/psql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .envs
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

Само по себе работает все прекрасно, изменения доставляются на лету, окружение изолировано. Но нет возможности дебажить через PyCharm и запускать отдельные тесты через тот же PyCharm.
Следуя документации, сделал так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логи запуска:

```
Removing django-first-ci-dev--web
django-first-ci-dev--postgres is up-to-date
Recreating 6eb846916022_django-first-ci-dev--web ... 
Attaching to django-first-ci-dev--web
django-first-ci-dev--web exited with code 0
Aborting on container exit...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

В логах контейнера пустота. Почему вырубается контейнер с Django? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Банальная невнимательность. Посмотрел, что происходит при запуске "Django Server".
В `Manage script` почему-то был прописан файл `settings.py`.

Исправил на `manage.py` и все стало работать, дебажиться и тестироваться :)